# having a problem with conditional operator in c

Tags: c, printf, scanf, conditional-operator, string-literals

I am trying to make a program to determine if the entered number is positive or negative with the conditional operator but when I enter the number the program doesn't print anything after

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{    
  char number;   
  char sum;

  printf("enter your number ");
  scanf("%d",&number);

  sum = (number > 0)?  "positive" : "negative";

  printf("your number is %s\n", sum);
}
```

Comment: Didn't you get any compiler warning such as `assignment to 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast`? Consider this as ans error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you mean the following

```
int number;

char *sum;

printf("enter your number ");

scanf("%d",&number);

sum = (number > 0)?  "positive" : "negative";

printf("your number is %s\n", sum);
```

That is the variable number should have the type `int` instead of `char`. Otherwise this call

```
scanf("%d",&number);
```

can invoke undefined behavior.

The variable `sum` should have the type `char *` instead of `char` because it is initialized by a string literal.

Pay attention to that if `number` is not greater than 0 it does not mean that it is a negative number. It can be equal to 0.:)

So this statement

```
sum = (number > 0)?  "positive" : "negative";
```

has a logical error. You could write at least like

```
sum = (number > 0)?  "positive" : "non-positive";
```

or use a more compound expression something like

```
sum = (number > 0) ?  "positive" : ( number == 0 ? "zero" : "negative" );
```

Answer (score 0):

`sum` holds a string, it should be defined as a `char*`, not a `char`.

Answer (score 0):

sum is character type and you are trying to save string in it. Either save a character in it or declare it as char*